# Laravel: I can't upload my dropzone file into my database

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

Hi I am new to laravel and javascript,

I have a multiple input forms for updating of product information including a image upload using Dropzone.js to update product image. However I cant see to update my image file as I keep getting a null value for my dropzone image when I have already dragged a file in.

Below are my codes in the **product-edit** page:

```php
<form action="{{ route('merchant.product.update', $product->prodID) }}" method="POST" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Code</h5>
        <input type="text" name="prodCode" class="form-control" id="prodCode" placeholder="Product Code" value="{{ old('prodCode', $product->prodCode) }}" required>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Description</h5>
        <textarea id="prodDesc" name="prodDesc" class="form-control" id="prodDesc" placeholder="Description" rows="5" required> {{ $product->prodDesc }}</textarea>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Price</h5>
        <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Price" value="{{ old('price', $product->price)}}">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Quantity</h5>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" value="{{ old('quantity', $product->quantity)}}">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Feature Product</h5>
        <div class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="featured" class="switch-input" value="1" {{ old('featured', $product->featured=="true") ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }}/>
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Product Image</h5>
        <div id="dropzoneDragArea" class="dz-default dz-message dropzoneDragArea">
            <span>Upload Image</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Update Product</button>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</form>
```

Below are the Javascript portion of the blade.php:
[image]

Below are my Controller Methods I have for the update:

```php
    public function storeImage(Request $request) {

        if($request->file('file')){
        // Upload path
        $destinationPath = 'img/products/';
        // Get File
        $image = $request->file('file');
        // Get File Name
        $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        // Uploading File to given path
        $image->move($destinationPath,$imageName);

        $product = new Product();
        $product->where('prodID', '=', $request->{'prodID'}, 'AND', 'created_by_merchant_id', '=', $this->checkMerchantID())
                ->update([
                    'prodImage' => $imageName,
                ]);
        }
        
    }

    //update Product details
    public function update(Request $request, $prodID)
    {
        if ($this->isCodeExist($request->{'prodCode'}, $request->{'prodID'})) {
            return back()->withErrors('This code already exists!');
        }        

        try{
        $db = new Product();
        $db->where('prodID', '=', $prodID, 'AND', 'created_by_merchant_id', '=', $this->checkMerchantID())
            ->update([
                'prodCode' => $request->{'prodCode'},
                'prodImage' =>$this->storeImage($request),
                'prodDesc' => $request->{'prodDesc'},
                'price' => $request->{'price'},
                'quantity' => $request->{'quantity'},
                'featured' => $request->input('featured') ? true : false,
            ]);
            return back()->with('success_message', 'Product updated successfully!');
            
            } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
                Log::channel('merchant_error')->error($ex);
                return back()->withErrors('There seems to be an error in updating');
            }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .. can u try `dd($request->all()` and add screen shot  and try `$request->{'prodID'}` to `$request->prodID`

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for the reply. Below are the dd($request->all()) output. Apologies I have no idea how to attached my screenshot below in the comment:

array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "iKkvOR8uLQD2EYsM9HrO3Q2xYSd072Tns1yLOwyL"
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "prodCode" => "32"
  "prodDesc" => "213"
  "price" => "232"
  "quantity" => "1"
  "featured" => "1"
]

Comment: in your reqest there is no `file` that's why it is not working

Comment: How do I get the file then? I used this video for the dropzone functions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aXhdc8tGFs